# Frequency response of a cascade opamp circuit using LTSpice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, frequency, bandwidth, bode-plot

I'm trying to simulate this circuit which consists of multiple stages of op amps, but I couldn't figure out the operating bandwidth of the circuit. Using AC analysis, the Bode plot is a weird shape and does not roll off type at certain frequencies. Why is this happening and what's the correct way to determine the break frequencies?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You appear to be looking for figures of merit that might help you pigeon-hole this circuit. I'd say the bode plot fully describes what is going on and searching for shorthand figures of merit is probably only going to help someone in management.

Comment: Side note: you should get more points per decade in your sweep. You might be missing out on some information (namely what is happening at around 10kHz)

Comment: Yes, it looks like you have a double pole instead of a single pole at 10K.